# What Russian letter is this?

Tags: алфавит, буквы, typography

Is the 4th letter a valid russian character?

[image]

When I copy the above word it is automatically converted to "сведения".

Comment: Yes, it's valid. And the conversion is also correct.

Comment: But how can i display the text in 1st format. when it is automatically converted to the 2nd one

Comment: Display where? I'm afraid this is a question, not related to the russian language. And there is no 1st format and the 2nd format, there is the only format. I believe that used char depends on the font.

Comment: @SwayamRaina You may note that for the latin alphabet some letters, in particular _a_ and _g_, look different than in other fonts.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/P6IfSCT.jpg

Comment: FYI, the word on @Quassnoi 's image is "лишишься"

Comment: @Quassnoi I was about to post this image too :) Good that I've noticed your comment...

Comment: @A.Toumantsev You could post a different one, with "дышишь", "слышишь", "лилии" etc.

Comment: It's purely the difference between upper and (handwritten) lower case. But you should say which application / website is doing the "conversion".

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The character "*д*" is the lowercase italic version of ["Д"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94), which both derive from the greek letter Delta (compare with "Δ", "δ"). In most fonts the straight lowercase letter is written as "д", while "*д*" is used in italic type. In some fonts (typically monospace console fonts or fonts designed for headings: Tahoma, Lucida Console, Franklin, Arial Bold, Century, Courier New) "д" is used in both straight and italic types. Capital letters are always written as "Д", even in italic type: "*Д*".

Wikipedia has a list of Cyrillic glypths which are substantially different when italized:
[image]

To make things even more confusing, there is [Russian cursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_cursive), or handwriting, which has different glyphs. In cursive, "д" will become similar to the Latin letter "g". In the picture below, it's the first letter on the last line:

[image]

Comment: That's pretty barmy! Mind you, us Westerners are just as guilty at least when it comes to uppercase/lowercase differences, so...

Comment: russian is a strange but interesting language to learn

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Cyrillic alphabet was initially derived from Greek, but adopted several latin glyphs when so-called [civil script](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82) was introduced in 1708 (funny, there's no English wikipedia article about it). So we have many script variants for some letters.

Comment: It's worth noting that although the g-looking d is the canonical form in handwriting, in everyday life people use the d-looking form just as they use a t-looking form for t although the canonical form looks like an m.  And while everyone is supposed to write clearly enough to distinguish a *ш* from a *т* without lines under/over the char, few do.

Comment: Sure, why not have m be the lowercase to T? Seems legit.

Comment: @corsiKa True, but the problem is actually not with 'm' (which was Russian 'T' all along), but with its [uppercase version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Te_%28Cyrillic%29#/media/File:20-Russian_alphabet-%D0%A2_%D1%82.svg) which got replaced by 'T'

Comment: @MMacD  "in everyday life people use the d-looking form" - maybe some do, I have never seen it.

Comment: @Anixx I have seen it, although the 'g' is the far more common version for me to see in handwriting, and the version I prefer as someone learning.

Comment: They should have marked *в* (cursive lowercase Ve) as well.

Answer (score 16):

It is a valid letter "д", the fifth letter of the alphabet. The glyph in the example is produced with a cursive/italic font. The other one is a glyph from a regular straight font.

Comment: So you are saying that this difference is due to italic/straight font

Comment: @SwayamRaina Yes, that's all it is, and there are two more lowercase letters with significantly different italic shapes: **г *г***, **т *т***.

Comment: Remark: cursive "д" is [different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet#/media/File:05-Russian_alphabet-%D0%94_%D0%B4.svg) yet.

Comment: For those not so familiar with cyrillic that's pretty bizarre to use different shape for italic font... Anyone know **why is that**? Perhaps for historic reasons? Readability?... Well, [found the answer](http://russian.stackexchange.com/a/1554/8074)

Comment: @PeterM How about Latin letters? Isn't it bizarre to have different shapes for upper and lower case and call a letter composed of two V's "double-U"?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Well, I was meant that *italic* is just font *style*, while upper/lower case letter is a bit different letter - with some meaning, like denoting sentence start. In latin, letter case is distinguished in handwriting, while *italics* not necessarily.

Comment: @PeterM I don't really agree, upper case is also a style where all letters have the same height. E.g. compare "PeterM" vs   "PᴇᴛᴇʀM". Also, check out how Latin *a* is written in italics, compared to straight type. There are many fonts (e.g Times New Roman) which have a glyph which looks like a *d* with a shorter vertical bar. So this is definitely not something unique to Russian.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I agree with PeterM. Upper case letters are *different* *glyphs* from lower-case letters, and both Roman and Cyrillic alphabets have upper and lower case, so that is not a point of contrast here. Your two versions of "PeterM" are "upper and lower case" and "upper case and small caps", which is yet another thing. Your point about roman and italic "a" is valid. But the OP was confused by a glyph which looked much more different from a roman д than an italic "a" compared to a roman "a".

Answer (score 5):

Every language has its quirkiness. With Russian,this is evident when one starts typing texts on a PC - and then formatting parts of it. Hence, the  *сведения* seems to differ from "сведения". But, this is solely due the use of italics.

This can be easily verified by copying "сведения" twice without a particular format, then mark one of these Russian words; changing its format to italics results in the text as you previously presented this word.

In my experience, attempting to find a font that shows no visible change when italicised is simply too time-consuming. Once one is aware of these Russian text quirks, one can concentrate on Russian cases and declensions!

Comment: *attempting to find a font that shows no visible change when italicised is simply too time-consuming* - on Windows, try Tahoma, Lucida Console, MS Sans Serif, Franklin, Arial Bold, Century, Courier New, Comic Sans, plus lots of Adobe fonts. You will be more limited on Linux, with (AFAIK) only some Liberation fonts preserving "д" in italics.

Comment: The edit needs to be rolled back, because currently this answer makes no sense at all. It may have something to do with the way the characters are displaying in Firefox?

Comment: @Flounderer oh, you are absolutely right. In Chrome it [also breaks it](http://russian.stackexchange.com/posts/13539/revisions). My fault, I just suggested a partial roll back of it.