# Is there any difference between "окно" and "окошко"?

Tags: выбор-слова

I had learned in a lesson that the word for `Window` in Russian was `Окно`. But later I noticed in the lyrics from `Молчат дома - судно`, that on the verse `Окошко, Тумбочка, Кровать`, Окошко stands for Window too.

Is there any difference between both or they are just two words for the same thing?

---

Unrelated:

Is it just me or the StackExchange Italic font messes up the Cyrillic alphabet? Кровать became *Кровать* in italic, the T turns to a m for some reason.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_cursive. Mobile version of Russian.SE uses a different font for italic, which is oblique and not italic proper

Comment: The small Т in Russian cursive is indeed usually written as m, and some italic fonts try to mimic the cursive т.

Comment: Related: [Why does italic 'т' look like 'm'](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/why-does-italic-%d1%82-look-like-m)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Окошко* is a diminutive for *окно*.

Russian readily uses diminutive forms for some nouns in their neutral meaning, like *солнышко* instead of *солнце*, *листок* instead of *лист*, *червяк* instead of *червь* etc.

They do a similar thing in British English: "telly" < "television", "leccy" < "electricity" and so on.

For some words, their original, non-diminutive form has become archaic or obsolete over the years: *ветка < ветвь, курица < кура, верёвка < вервь* etc.

Comment: ветвь - seriously, archaic or obsolete? вервь - never heard of this word, hence i can assume is obsolete, but two other examples - are still in use, and not archaic. кура - i think is extensively in use on farm markets.

Comment: @dEmigOd: I agree, but "солнь" really existed. "солнце" was a diminutive itself. So "солнышко" is a diminutive of diminutive. Reference book: Лев Успенский "Слово о словах".

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add, that "окно" but not "окошко" sometimes can be used in the meaning "period of time".

Окно — промежуток времени в расписании работ, занятий и т. п.
Окно — плановый перерыв в движении поездов;
Окно у учителей — незанятый урок;
Окно у ракетчиков — расчётный период времени, в течение которого должна быть запущена ракета для вывода космического аппарата на определённую орбиту.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the diminutive form, however, I would also distinguish another case where those 2 words differ is when we talk about size.
In Russian *Окно* - is a window standard or big size, but *Окошко* could be quite a small window furthermore it could be even a window from toy house.